# Outputting an Ipleaflet widget in Google Colaboratory

Tags: jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

In [Google Colaboratory](https://colab.research.google.com) I have tried installing [Ipleaflet](https://github.com/jupyter-widgets/ipyleaflet) using the command:

```
!pip install ipyleaflet

!jupyter nbextension enable --py --sys-prefix ipyleaflet
```

Which according to the output gets installed correctly however when I use the code:

```
from ipyleaflet import Map, basemaps, basemap_to_tiles

m = Map(center=(52.204793, 360.121558), zoom=9)

dark_matter_layer = basemap_to_tiles(basemaps.CartoDB.DarkMatter)
m.add_layer(dark_matter_layer)
m
```

The output I recieve is the text:

**Map(basemap={'url': 'https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', 'max_zoom': 19, 'attribution': 'Map …**
rather than the map.

Is there a way to get Google-Colaboratory to be able to output this kind of a widget? Are there additional libraries that need to be installed?

I have tested the code (taken from the Ipleaflet documentation) in a Jupyter notebook on my PC and it works fine.

Comment: For the answer to the question please look to Korakot's reply. 

For those of you wishing to use Map Visualisations in Colab I would suggest installing Bokeh:

https://colab.research.google.com/notebook#fileId=/v2/external/notebooks/charts.ipynb&scrollTo=vlOIt0zZ5uCz

You can then use their mapping function: https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/reference/models/map_plots.html

Make sure you include:
from bokeh.io import output_notebook
output_notebook()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ipyleaflet doesn't work with colab yet.

Colab doesn't support anything using Jupyter widgets.

You can also use `folium`. It also uses leaflet inside. I make an example notebook [here](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1AZXs7vQGmHkXnxdeiVCrP6NKG3eMVkLc).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Did some more research and found that Bokeh can work in the Jupyter Notebook: 
https://colab.research.google.com/notebook#fileId=/v2/external/notebooks/charts.ipynb&scrollTo=vlOIt0zZ5uCz

and it also has a map plotting library: 
https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/reference/models/map_plots.html

Comment: In addition to bokeh, you can also use plotly and folium. After a few trials, I prefer folium(which use leaflet inside).

I made a notebook for each of them (sorry that I commented in Thai there)
 
Folium: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1AZXs7vQGmHkXnxdeiVCrP6NKG3eMVkLc

Plotly: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1NHT2sxZqg8Qn75nbHZCdbaxrEtUQbuFe